# Using "NOT IN" select in ADODB.Connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to pull data in current Excel from another workbook, and I want to prevent reading duplicate data, because the macro will be run on the user's excel file on the weekend, so I would use "Not In" select SQL to read only new data by writing two ADODB.Connection :

```
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [A1:J10000]"
    cn.Open strCon
    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1, 1
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
 
Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SourceFile = "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test.xlsm"
SourceRange$ = "A1:J10000"
SourceSheet$ = "Data"

szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=yes"";"

szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "] WHERE [Name] Not in (select [Name] from rs) ;"
 
    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
    sheet4.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
```

I get this error after running :
[image: ADODB.Connection.Error]

Comment: rs only exists in your code. In the SQL for the second query try replacing it with as sub-query.

Comment: No sir, rs is used only for one time :
rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1, 1
And I used it in "szSQL " as a recordset

Comment: You reference rs as a subdataset in rsCon. rsCon connection does not know what rs is. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to combine data from multiple VBA workbook connections into one query. At least, I've never seen it and can't find anything. Might have to bring data from external workbook into a sheet of active workbook. Or maybe explore MS PowerQuery add-in app. It might be able to see both workbooks and build nested query.

Comment: Doesn't matter where this VBA is (Excel, Access, Word, etc), it is not possible for one recordset to embed another recordset in its SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a query which references two different workbooks:

```vba
Sub CrossFileQuery()

    Dim fold As String, fPath1, fPath2
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
    
    fold = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    fPath1 = fold & "Source1.xlsx"
    fPath2 = fold & "Source 2.xlsx"
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
              "Data Source = " & fPath1 & _
              ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
              
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    rs.Open " select a.* from [Sheet1$] a " & _
            " where a.FirstCol not in " & _
            " (select b.FirstCol from [" & fPath2 & "].[Sheet1$] b)", conn
    
    With Sheet1.Range("A1")
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was great.